# How can I connect Log Analytics Workspace via rest api with Azure Data Factory without Authentication

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-rest-api, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I want to retrieve data from the result of a query in Log analytics workspace, I tried to do that using pipeline, where as the first function I got the Web activity, configured as follows:
[image]

[image] I followed this example:https://datasavvy.me/2020/12/24/retrieving-log-analytics-data-with-data-factory/
Then I got Copy data activity:
[image]
request method: post
request body:

```
{
    "query": "ADFPipelineRun | project PipelineName, Status,TimeGenerated,  _ResourceId, Type | where Status == 'Succeeded'"
}| ConvertTo-Json
```

two headers:
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Authentication: @concat('Bearer ', activity('GetBearerToken').output.access_token)
[image]

I get this error when I debugged:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect Log Analytics Workspace via rest api with Azure Data Factory without Authentication.

**First you need to get a bearer token, which gives you the authorization to execute the query.** To get this follow below steps:

- Create an Azure AD App in Azure Active Directory and note down the **tenant Id, Client Id and client secret.** (In your workspace grant IAM privileges to the AAD Application you created as Contributor) Now in ADF Create a pipeline and take web activity to get bearer token.

> URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Apps_tenant_ID>/oauth2/token
> Method: POST
> Body: grant_type=client_credentials &client_id=<Apps_Client_ID>&resource=https://api.loganalytics.io/&client_secret=<Apps_Client_Secret>
> Header :  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

[image]

Bearer token:

[image]

- To query Log analytics from Rest API. create a linked service for Rest API with below settings.

> Base URL: https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/<Workspace_Id>/query
> [image]

Source settings:

> Request method: POST
> Request Body: {"query": "search * | where PipelineName contains 'pipe'"}
> Headers: "Content-Type:application/json"
> "Authorization: @concat('Bearer ',activity('Web2').output.access_token)"

[image]

- Add appropriate SINK and run the pipeline.